# CMake Add own library to project using find_library()

Tags: cmake, clion

I am currently creating a set of classes that should be used in
 different projects using CLion. My question is how do I implement this
 functionality.

So far I looked into the following related issues
 which didn't really solve my problem:

- [CMake link to external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)
- [Add external libraries to CMakeList.txt c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070488/cmake-link-an-external-library)
- CMake reference for add_library(), find_library() which I don't fully understand yet since I am fairly new to CMake

I created two sample projects "TestLib" and "TestProj":

- TestLib

  - src

    - Class.h

      Class.cpp

    CMakeList.txt

- TestProj

  - main.cpp

    CMakeList.txt

The *CMakeList.txt* for "TestLib" currently looks as follows:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
 project(TestLib)

 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++0x")

 set(SOURCE_FILES src/Class.cpp src/Class.h)
 add_library(TestLib ${SOURCE_FILES})>
```

Now, I tried to use this library in "TestProj" using the following
 *CMakeLists.txt*:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
 project(TestProj)

 set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++0x")
 find_library(CLASS_LIB TestLib HINTS /home/user/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/TestLib-7507f101/7507f101/Debug)

 set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
 add_executable(TestProj ${SOURCE_FILES})

 target_link_libraries(TestProj CLASS_LIB)
```

CMake finds the library but

1. I dont have access to *Class.h* of the library
2. Writing the whole /home/user/.CLion2016.1/...-Path to the library seems to be wrong

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake link to external library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the goal is to make your library available to multiple other projects, the recommended way to do that would be to have your library project's install procedure generate CMake configuration files.  Unfortunately, the procedure to do that is a bit arcane, but https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages should give you a starting point on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put at the root of your projects CMakeLists.txt
with such content:

```
add_subdirectory(TestLib)
add_subdirectory(TestProj)
```

after that you can write in TestProj's CMakeLists.txt just

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../TestLib)
target_link_libraries(TestProj TestList)
```

and no need to use `find_library`

Comment: Did you mean `target_link_libraries(TestProj TestLib)` ?