# Linking an external library bundle file on macos with cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a library compiled as a single file that I'm trying to link with `cmake` but haven't been able to cobble together something that works using existing examples that should be related, eg.

[CMake link an external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070488/cmake-link-an-external-library)
[Cmake linking external libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52028809/cmake-linking-external-libraries)

What I have so far:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(atem)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(BMD_API_LIB "BMDSwitcherAPI")
set(BMD_API_PATH "/Library/Application Support/Blackmagic Design/Switchers/BMDSwitcherAPI.bundle/Contents/MacOS/")

find_library(BMDSwitcherAPI ${BMD_API_LIB} PATHS ${BMD_API_PATH})

add_executable(atem main.cpp BMDSwitcherAPIDispatch.cpp)

target_link_libraries(atem ${BMDSwitcherAPI})
```

The files `main.cpp` and `BMDSwitcherAPIDispatch.cpp` exist in the same directory. Building says that the file for the library can't be found, but the binary for the library file for `${BMD_API_LIB}` cannot be found, but it is definitely at the path given in `${BMD_API_PATH}`.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Edit: added entire error message

```
====================[ Build | atem | Debug ]====================================
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake --build /Users/user/Code/atem/cmake-build-debug --target atem -- -j 9
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable atem
ld: library not found for -lBMDSwitcherAPI
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [atem] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/atem.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/atem.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [atem] Error 2
```

Comment: @Tsyvarev added entire error output.

Comment: `find_library` should store into the variable, passed to it as the first parameter, an **absolute path**. But the message from the linker implies relative path. You may try to perform **clean reconfiguration** of the project, that is removing `CMakeCache.txt` from the build directory and run `cmake` again.

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't help. I think it's possible that the symbol for the library isn't actually `BMDSwitcherAPI`, and it's not documented by the vendor what else it would be

Comment: Whatever vendor tells, `find_library` shouldn't assign `BMDSwitcherAPI` value to `BMDSwitcherAPI` variable. You may add `message(STATUS "BMDSwitcherAPI: ${BMDSwitcherAPI"}` after `find_library` call and may check what it will print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be helpful to anyone else because it was so specific to the one library I was using, but here it is anyway.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(atem)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
find_library(CoreFoundation_Library CoreFoundation)
mark_as_advanced(CoreFoundation_Library)
set(
    SWITCHERS_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR
    /Applications/Blackmagic\ ATEM\ Switchers/Developer\ SDK/Mac\ OS\ X/include/
)
add_executable(
    atem
    atem/main.cpp
    ${SWITCHERS_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR}/BMDSwitcherAPIDispatch.cpp
)
target_include_directories(atem PRIVATE ${SWITCHERS_SDK_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(atem ${CoreFoundation_Library})
```